# Using JArray for serializing data from database in WebAPI (C#)

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I want to achieve the following JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "name":"Deutschland",
    "code":"de"
  },
  {
    "name":"Frankreich",
    "code":"fr"
  },
  {
    "name":"Japan",
    "code":"jpn"
  }
]
```

Currently I'm getting this result of JSON data:

```
{
    "groups":[
        {
            "name":"Deutschland",
            "code":"de"
        },
        {
            "name":"Frankreich",
            "code":"fr"
        },
        {
            "name":"Japan",
            "code":"jpn"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the code of the Controller:

```
public dynamic GetGroups()
{
  JObject o = JObject.FromObject(new
  {
     groups = from g in db.QR_Groups
              select new
              {
                name = g.name,
                code = g.code
              }
  });

  return o;

  /*Here I've tried to get JSON data as array without the Property "groups"*/
  //JArray a = new JArray(
  //            from g in db.QR_Groups
  //            select new JValue(g));

  //return a;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to retrieve the JSON data as per the first JSON example above?

And is the type "dynamic" good practice for the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all there is no need to do serialization manually. ASP.Net WebApi `MediaFormatters` are going to take care of it based on the `Request Content-Type`. So Create a class as shown below.

```
public class Group
{        
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

Then your Web API endpoint should be -

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetCountries()
{
    List<Group> groups = (from g in db.QR_Groups
                               select new Group
                               {
                                   name = g.name,
                                   code = g.code
                               }).ToList();

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, groups);
}
```

And when I make a Fiddler request, I was able to get the output which you are interested -

[image]

Comment: How can I do this with `public IQueryable<Group> GetGroups()`?

Comment: No, I don't. Is it necessary?

Comment: For typical `OData` endpoints, we return `IQueryable` results, or else just return `HttpResponseMessage` as shown above.

Comment: But the DataAnnotation [HttpGet] isn't necessary or?

Comment: It is not necessary, but it is good if you specify the action is GET, PUT, POST etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(from g in db.QR_Groups
            select new
            {
                name = g.name,
                code = g.code
            });
```

> And is the type "dynamic" good practice for the method?

no, it's not best practise. Better one is to create new class

Comment: I have a class Group.. I've tried `public IQueryable<Group> GetGroups` but I've never got the JSON data result.

Comment: this is because `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` returns json `string` rather than `IQueryable<Group>`

Comment: and how can I return `IQueryable<Group>`?

Comment: if you want to return `IQueryable<Group>` you don't need to convert it to `Json`. Just fetch data from db and return from method: `return from g in db.QR_Groups select new Group {...}`